# css: make content in fixed-positioned div scrollable

Tags: css

I have a page with some content, and a toolbar to edit this content. The toolbar is positioned fixed to the right of the page. The insides of the toolbar should also be scrollable.

How do I make the insides of this toolbar scrollable? Right now, when I hover over the toolbar and scroll, it results in scrolling the background, not the toolbar content.

I tried

```
 overflow-y: scroll;
```

and

```
 overflow-y: auto;
```

these did not help.

**UPDATE:**

Only one of columns inside the toolbar needs to be scrollable.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kyqr5xst/12/

Comment: You can add `height: 100%` to your `.column`

Comment: adding overflow-y in class "fixed_div" does it for you? --> .fixed_div {
  overflow-y:auto;
}

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.fixed_div
{
  overflow: auto;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fixed nav add `height:auto` `overflow:auto` This will make it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto;` to the `.fixed_div`

```css
.fixed_div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  
  overflow:auto;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  
}

.column {
  color: grey;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Background text
</h1>
<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>
<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>
<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>

<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>

<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>

<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>

<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>

<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>
<div class="fixed_div">
  <div class="column">
  <h2>Toolbar Content (needs scrolling on hover)
</h2>
  <p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>
<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>
<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>
<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>
<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specified.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>
<p>
This lorem ipsum generator is made for all the webdesigners, designers, webmasters and others who need lorem ipsum. Generator is made the way that everyone can use it, but especially for projects which need html markup. You can decide which html tags you want and our generator will generate just as you specifi.
Pretty cool, isn't it?
</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ot9d7kju/5/